# Data sent through NSData is only partially received

Tags: swift, nsdata, gamekit

Trying to write a small real-time card game using GameKit and GKMatch.
I've followed [this Game Center tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/60998/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-2) (in Objective-C), but are now stuck trying to convert this to Swift 2.

My enums and structs:

```
enum Messagetype:Int {
        case kMessageTypeRandomNumber = 0
        case kMessageTypeGameBegin = 1
        case kMessageTypeMove = 2
        case kMessageTypeGameOver = 3
    }

struct Message {
    var messageType:Messagetype = .kMessageTypeMove
}

struct MessageRandomNumber {
    var message = Message()
    var randomNumber: Int = -1
}

var ourRandomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(100000))+1
```

fun sendRandomNumber()

```
func sendRandomNumber() {
        var message = MessageRandomNumber()

        message.randomNumber = self.ourRandomNumber
        message.message.messageType = .kMessageTypeRandomNumber

        let data = NSData(bytes: &message, length: sizeof(MessageRandomNumber))
        self.sendData(data)
        print ("Random number \(message.randomNumber) sent from \(localPlayer.alias!)")
}
```

func sendData

```
func sendData(data: NSData) {

        let gameKitHelper = GameKitHelper.sharedGameKitHelper
        var succes:Bool? = true

        do {
            try gameKitHelper.match.sendDataToAllPlayers(data, withDataMode: .Reliable)
            } catch {
                succes = nil
            }
            if succes == nil {
                print ("Error sending data.")
        }
}
```

func match.didReceiveData

```
func match(match: GKMatch, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromRemotePlayer player: GKPlayer) {
        print ("Data received.")
        let message:Message = UnsafePointer<Message>(data.bytes).memory as Message

        if (message.messageType == .kMessageTypeRandomNumber) {
            let messageRandomNumber:MessageRandomNumber = UnsafePointer<MessageRandomNumber>(data.bytes).memory as MessageRandomNumber

            print ("Received random number \(messageRandomNumber.randomNumber)")
}
```

I can see in the logs that a random number <> 0 is chosen and sent using sendRandomNumber from a device.

stepping through didReceiveData I see that:

1. message.messageType = .kMessageTypeRandomNumber (which is different from the value the struct was initialized with. Also, this value was set in sendRandomNumber, so I believe this part gets sent correctly).
2. messageRandomNumber.message.messageType = .kMessageTypeRandomNumber (again correct)
3. However, messageRandomNumber.randomNumber is always 0 (which is not correct)

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

didReceiveData is called when *some* data is received. It is called again when *more* data is received. You have to collect the data (or process it as it comes in, aware that it is incomplete) and there is another callback when the data is complete.

Comment: Thanks. That makes complete sense, however I can't seem to find this in Apple's documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/GKMatchDelegate/match:didReceiveData:fromRemotePlayer:)

Comment: Oops, pressed send too quick on mobile. Can you point me in de right direction where I can find how I should do this in Swift?

Comment: Can I use EnumerateByteRangesUsingBlock for this perhaps instead of directly accessing the bytes property?